# vmware windows7 professional changing ip addresses

Tags: networking, windows-7, vmware-fusion

is there a way to fix your windows 7 professional guest host os ipaddress so it does not change every time you startup?  I am currently using NAT for networking and would like to remain using this networking method if possible.  In older versions of windows this never used to be a problem in vmware so I am wondering if I am missing a setting in windows 7 professional or in vmware.

thank you for your help,
chris

Comment: I'm on VMWare Workstation 6.5.1 and the IP of a Windows 7 prof. guest stays the same after restarts. I'd recommend to check DHCP lease duration in Virtual Network Editor for the NAT virtual host adapter (usually VMNet8).

Comment: this is a great idea, I am giving that a try now, I expanded the setting to 864000 with a max of 900000

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with an Ubuntu guest and couldn't change to a static IP, and fixed using the following:

You can allocate a static lease for behind NAT by adding it here (Win 7, VMWare Player 5):-

`C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\VMware\vmnetdhcp.conf`

```
host UbuntuVM {
    hardware ethernet 00:0c:29:b7:86:ab;
    fixed-address 192.168.216.99;
}
```

- you add it before the final `#end`
- you need to change the example 192.168.216 above to your subnet
- maybe allocate outside of the DHCP pool. I believe this is 123-254 so chose 99
- you need to edit the security on the file to get permission to save it.
- stop the vm before and restart the vmware dhcp service after you've saved the change

from: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/341785

Answer (score 0):

here is what worked for me: http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2009/11/26/windows-7-static-ip/

not sure its 100% but so far after 2 reboots its working as expected